# Android Studio Dolphin issue with ?actionBarSize

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio Dolphin (released on 1 September, 2022) could not resolve ?actionBarSize.

Comment: can you share that error.

Comment: Add some more details. Then we are able to resolve it.

Comment: I updated AS to Dolphin and xml is not showing. When I saw the logs, it said that couldn't find ?actionBarSize. I deleted AS and downloaded an older version. It works fine at the moment.